# App Store iphone app version description. How is it set?

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store, plist

I have a question about the information displayed on the App Store.
There are some iPhone apps that have the following info set on the App Store:
Category: Finance
Updated: 27 January 2011
Current Version: 1.32
1.32 (iOS 4.0 tested)
Size: 1.3 MB
Languages: English, Greek
Developer: ABCDEF Limited
@2011 ABCDEF Limited

My question is how do they set the "1.32 (iOS 4.0 tested)". I've tried a couple of things on the plist file but they were rejected.

Any thoughts on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `iOS 4.0 tested` option is prompted when uploading app by the `Application Loader.app`.

Comment: What do you mean? When I submit the app, set for Release and click on Build & Archive. Then from the Organizer I validate, and then I submit. The only option prompted is for login credentials and to select the App Store Profile.

Comment: Have you ever upload the iPhone app by the `Application Loader.app`, usually inside `/Developer/Applications/Utilities` folder?

Comment: no, I use the Build and Archive process, which brings the Organizer window up. Then follow the process I mentioned. As far as I know this is the official process. I have the latest released SDK and Xcode. not the Beta

Comment: You will use the `Application Loader.app` when you upload the app to AppStore and you will see the prompt mentioned.

Comment: I will try the Loader next time. Thank you for your input

Answer (score 1):

For setting v1.32 have a look at `CFBundleShortVersionString` (Bundle versions string, short) and `CFBundleVersion` (Bundle version) keys. Also see the [SO 1784209 and similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784209/plist-bundle-version-values)

As ohho wrote: The `iOS tested` is asked by Xcode or App loader during upload.